# TOPIK exam discussion and group study chat room

Tags: discussion

I want to do an experiment on boosting the visitor numbers to our website

This year's Korean language evaluation test (TOPIK) will be held on Oct. 20-21 and I am sure there are many people self preparing for the test

I would like to invite you to the newly formed TOPIK study chat room at
https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84036/topik-bang

Whether you are preparing alone or are already in a class and just want some more discussion partners, you are welcome to join

I will try to be available in the room during 8pm to 9pm KST for discussions, but anyone is welcome to come and use the chat room at any time based on their convenience. I hope that we can use this room to discuss old TOPIK questions, sample tests and share resources.

EDIT:
This chatroom has been deactivated for now. However, if anyone is interested in participating in a TOPIK discussion chatroom, please leave a comment to this post.